# how to output numbers as strings/names

Tags: java, string, random, int, generator

I'm writing the code for a **HiLo card game** in which the player has to guess whether the next card drawn will be *higher*, *lower* or *equal*.
Although for the numbers `11`, `12`, `13` and `1`, I'd like the output to be *Jack*, *Queen*, *King* and *Ace*.

I've worked out the program to point where it returns a random `int` between `0` and `13`  (I'm still unaware as to how I would write the code to make it only choose random `int` between `1` and `13`).
How do I set it so the `11`, `12`, `13` and `1` numbers appear as

```
The Card pulled is the Ace, 
is the next card Higher, Lower or Equal?
```

and so on, I've tried `if` statements and changing `int` to `String`, but neither work, and to my avail was nothing I was able to find about a String generator...

Here is my code, any help would be greatly appreciated

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class HiLo {

    public static final int JACK = 11;
    public static final int QUEEN = 12;
    public static final int KING = 13;
    public static final int ACE = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int correctGuesses = 0;

        Random generator = new Random();
        int currentCard;
        int nextCard = generator.nextInt( KING+1 );

        while (correctGuesses < 4) {
            currentCard = nextCard;
            nextCard = generator.nextInt( KING+1 );

            Object[] options = {"Higher",
                "Lower",
            "Equal"};
            int Input = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
            "The Card pulled is the " + currentCard +
            " \nis the next card Higher, Lower or Equal?",
            "HiLo Card Game",
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
            null, options, options[0]);

            if(nextCard > currentCard) {
                switch(Input) {
                    case JOptionPane.YES_OPTION:
                        correctGuesses++;
                        break;
                    case JOptionPane.NO_OPTION:
                    case JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION:
                        correctGuesses = 0;
                        break;
                }
            } else if(nextCard < currentCard) {
                switch(Input) {
                    case JOptionPane.NO_OPTION:
                        correctGuesses++;
                        break;
                    case JOptionPane.YES_OPTION:
                    case JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION:
                        correctGuesses = 0;
                        break;
                }
            } else {
                switch(Input) {
                    case JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION:
                        correctGuesses++;
                        break;
                    case JOptionPane.YES_OPTION:
                    case JOptionPane.NO_OPTION:
                        correctGuesses = 0;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  
            "Congratulations, You guessed correctly 4 times,"
        + "\nthe Last Card was the " + nextCard + ", resart to play again" );
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change currentCard to a String. Then instead of

```
currentCard = nextCard;
```

do

```
currentCard = Integer.toString(nextCard);
```

Then you can do your if statements and assign the strings you need to for the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
String getCardString(int card) {

    String cardString = null;

    switch (card) {
        ACE:
            cardString = "ace";
            break;
        KING:
            cardString = "king";
            break;
        // same for queen and jack
        DEFAULT:
            cardString = Integer.toString(nextCard);
    }
       return cardString;
}


JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  
            "Congratulations, You guessed correctly 4 times,"
        + "\nthe Last Card was the " + getCardString(nextCard) + ", resart to play again" );
```

For the random generator, you can generate between 0 and 12, then add 1:

```
nextCard = ACE + generator.nextInt(KING);
```

Comment: how would this way specify if Queen was higher than jack or the opposite?

Comment: You will use ace, queen, jack and king as number everywhere, except where you will display results to the user. Just call `getCardString(int card)` (I forgot the argument on the example) when you will generate the string message to the user.